# Laravel posting base64 file via HTTP client is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-api

I'm implementing third party API in Laravel where I have to send some data along with fileData with base64.

Like this:

[image]

To post the data I'm sending like this:

```
$requestUrl = $this->baseUrl . $endpoint;

$content = [
    'associatedType' => 'property',
    'associatedId' => 'XXXXXXX81',
    'typeId' => 'DET',
    'name' => '304-Smithson-Road-Details.pdf',
    "isPrivate" => false,
    'fileData' => 'data:application/pdf;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8BQDwAEhQGAhKmMIQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
];

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    "api-version" => config("apiVersion"),
    "customer" => config("customer"),
    "Accept" => "application/json-patch+json",
    "Authorization" => "Bearer {$this->token}"
])->send($method, $requestUrl, [
    "body" => json_encode($content)
])->collect()->toArray();

return $response;
```

After executing the above code I'm getting null response and file is not uploaded.

Is there any mistake in HTTP request code?

Comment: You are not specifying the correct Content-Type?

Comment: Which need to be set?

Comment: `application/json-patch+json`, according to the screenshot.

Comment: I have added but still not uploading.